# I am handling error to skip to next step when error threw.On the first time error working fine,Second time Throwing error

Tags: excel, vba

the below code is working perfectly at the first time error but throwing error on second time.I am getting error at `cn.execute(Sql)`So i want to skip this to next whenever getting error and continue loop

```
'EXECUTION OF SQL QUERY
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    Set Sql = ws.Range("D" & m)
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    Set Rec_set = cn.Execute(Sql) 'Issue SQL statement
    Status = Worksheets("Count").Range("B" & m).Value
    Application.StatusBar = "Table Executing :" & Status
    While Not Rec_set.EOF
    ws.Range("E" & m).CopyFromRecordset Rec_set
    Wend
    Rec_set.Close 'Close the recordset

           'FILE UPLOAD
'Mention the SHarePoint Address and directly upload into SharePoint
 ws.Range("D" & m & ":" & "E" & m).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  "" & sFolder & "/_Count_Row" & m & ".pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    With ws
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("F" & m).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
            Address:="" & sFolder & "/Count_Row" & m & ".pdf", _
            ScreenTip:="Hyperlink", _
            TextToDisplay:="Count_Row" & m
    Application.StatusBar = "File is being uploded into SharePoint for the table :" & Status
    End With
errHandler:
Next m
```

I tried `Resume next` after `errHandler:`still throwing error
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: There's no need in a loop when dumping records to sheet. You need to replace `While Not Rec_set.EOF:  ws.Range("E" & m).CopyFromRecordset Rec_set: Wend` to just `ws.Range("E" & m).CopyFromRecordset`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the errors with `Resume Next`, then you have to clear them as well.

Thus, on the line after (or before) `Resume Next` write `Err.Clear`. This is some small example how to use `Err.Clear`, although it looks quite like spaghetti code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long
    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    For cnt = 1 To 10
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If cnt Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Debug.Print cnt / 0
            Else
                Debug.Print cnt / 2
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:

    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") "
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried errhandler.Clear,but its not working as expected

Comment: Thanks Vityata.
Err.Clear is not working throwing error as method or data member not found

Comment: I tried like this
on Error goto errhandler:
code here
errHandler:
errHandler.Clear
Next m

Throwing error as object required

Comment: @abinaya - so you are not having an object. Which line is the one with the error?

Comment: Yes i created err as object and tried then its showing error as "Object variable or with block variable not set 
Err1.Clear ( I defined Public Err1 As ADODB.Error and Err1 as object)

Comment: @abinaya - I have no idea, sry. You should probably provide more of the code and state exaclty what you are intending to do and where the error is appearing. :)

Answer (score -1):

i used below code and working fine:

```
errHandler:
On Error GoTo -1
Next M
```

Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: All you're doing with this is ignoring the error rather than handling it.  You could end up with incorrect results when it fails (and incorrect results are much worse than code that _appears_ to work fine).

Comment: if any incorrect results ,we can check it after complete this loop.This is based on my requirement